# Тестирование GET-запроса

Tags: json, get, rest

Написал такой тест,запрос возвращает правильные данные,но проблема в формате этих данных:

```
    @Test
    public void findWayByIdWith3stepsTest() throws Exception {
       List<Point> correctPath = Arrays.asList(new Point(0, 3), new Point(1, 3), new Point(1, 2), new Point(2, 2));

       when(fieldsRepository.findOne(1)).thenReturn(firstCorrectResult);

       mockMvc.perform(get("/1.0/way/{id}/findway/steps/{steps}", 1, 3))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType((new MediaTypeService().applicationJsonUTF8())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.path", is(correctPath)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.movingState", is("moving")));

}

java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.path"
Expected: is <[0=3, 1=3, 1=2, 2=2]>
     but: was <[{"key":0,"value":3},{"key":1,"value":3},{"key":1,"value":2},{"key":2,"value":2}]>
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как исправить данну проблему?

Comment: Если вы оформите код в качестве текста, а не скриншотами, то будет легче его смотреть. И скажите, что вас не устраивает в формате, какой он должен быть по вашему мнению, так как данные у вас правильные.

Comment: Проблема вот в чём : мои правильные данные - List<Point> correctPath.Запрос возвращает объект,одно из полей которого "path" - так же List<Point>.Пытаясь протестировать этот запрос,я столкнулся с данной проблемой : данные правильные,но почему-то формат возвращаемых данных не позволяет правильно сравнивать)